# File /etc/ld.so.nohwcap is missing in Debian 7

Tags: linux, debian

What is the file `/etc/ld.so.nohwcap` used for?. In my machine (`Debian 7`), this file is not found. Therefore, Which package or library this file belongs to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't belong to any package.  It's a configuration file you create to modify the behaviour of the dynamic linker.

`man ld.so` provides the detail.

> /etc/ld.so.nohwcap
>
> When this file is present the dynamic linker will load the non-optimized version of a library, even if the CPU supports the optimized version.

Although no reference is made to the file in `man ld.so` on Jessie (Debian 8), the behaviour has not changed.

Comment: The behaviour hasn't changed in Debian 8, just the documentation.

Comment: I agree, the behavior doesn't seem to have changed.  According to `strace`, at least one program still checks for that file when loading: `ls`.

Comment: @daveloyall, it is not the `ls` program that is checking for this file,. but the dynamic linker `ld.so` which is used in almost any program, including `ls`.

Comment: Yes, exactly.  Thank you for stating it clearly!